# SP returns positive RecordsAffected value even when TSQL statement rolled back

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to build an all-or-nothing TSQL statement, something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    -- Loop over a TVP passed as a param
    DECLARE i CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT [stmt] FROM TVP param;
    OPEN i;
    FETCH NEXT FROM i INTO @iDB, @iTBL, @iATTRS, @iVALS;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @SQL = next row of TVP
            EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @SQL
        END
    CLOSE i;
    DEALLOCATE i;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

The SP generally works as intended, in that the transactions are all or nothing, and running the SP from SSMS returns the error as selected in the catch statement.

But on the C# side, the `dbResponse.RecordsAffected` value is always incremented.

Why is this? Also, how can I get this SP to return the correct rows effected value? (i.e. the number of rows that were effected by the SP on success)

Is it possible to reset this value in the CATCH statement?

Comment: Try `set nocount on` to see if that helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> on the C# side, the dbResponse.RecordsAffected value is always incremented.

That's just a total of the row count messages returned from SQL Server.  These are sent as queries are run, before the transaction has been committed or rolled back.

> how can I get this SP to return the correct rows effected value?

Keep track of the row count in a variable, and return that to the client with an output parameter or a result set.

> Is it possible to reset this value in the CATCH statement?

As @Kin suggested, you can SET NOCOUNT ON and no rowcount messages will be sent to the client.  Then after you COMMIT you can turn NOCOUNT OFF and run a query to that generates the desired rowcount message. Perhaps something cheezy like:

```
set nocount on
--do stuff
declare @rows int = 25



set nocount off
select top (@rows) 1 a
into #bitbucket
from sys.objects o, sys.columns c
```

Comment: Thanks this works as I want it to. what is the #bitbucket? is this using tempdb?

Comment: I don't know any way to manufacture a rowcount message other than running a query that actually affects that many rows.  They cheapest way I could think of was to insert that many rows into a single-column temp table.